# How to fix C# code to push folder to GitHub repository

Tags: c#, github, github-api, winui-3

I am attempting to develop a WinUI 3 application to push the files in a folder on my local machine to an existing private GitHub repository. However, I when run the code shown below, nothing gets pushed to GitHub.

```
public async Task PushFolderToGitHub()
{
    string folderPath = "C:\\TestFolder"
    string repoOwner = "my_github_username";
    string repoName = "my_repo_name";
    string token = "my_github_PAT";

    var baseAddress = "https://api.github.com";
    var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress) };
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.Add(new ProductInfoHeaderValue("MyApp", "1.0"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Token", token);

    var rootFolder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(folderPath);
    var files = await rootFolder.GetFilesAsync();

    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        var content = new StringContent(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(file.Path), Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain");
        var path = $"{rootFolder.Name}/{file.Name}";
        var requestUri = $"/repos/{repoOwner}/{repoName}/contents/{path}";
        try
        {
            var response = await client.PutAsync(requestUri, content);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Debug.WriteLine(responseString);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Log the exception or display an error message
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return;
        }

    }
}
```

I debugged this, and found that the line `var response = await client.PutAsync(requestUri, content);` returned the following value for "response":

*response   {StatusCode: 403, ReasonPhrase: 'Forbidden', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
Cache-Control: no-cache
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 0
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'; style-src 'unsafe-inline'
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
}}  System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage*

I have double checked that my username and PAT are correct, so I do not understand why this is happening. If anyone could share any ideas on how I could fix this, then I would greatly appreciate it.

Update: On doing some further research I found that all GitHub API calls must include the User Agent header, so I added the following line of code as shown above: `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.Add(new ProductInfoHeaderValue("MyApp", "1.0"));`. As a result the value for response is now as follows:

*-      response    {StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
Server: GitHub.com
Date: Thu, 16 Feb 2023 07:00:12 GMT
X-OAuth-Scopes: admin:enterprise, admin:gpg_key, admin:org, admin:org_hook, admin:public_key, admin:repo_hook, admin:ssh_signing_key, audit_log, codespace, delete:packages, delete_repo, gist, notifications, project, repo, user, workflow, write:discussion, write:packages
X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes: repo
github-authentication-token-expiration: 2023-03-13 12:19:42 UTC
X-GitHub-Media-Type: github.v3
x-github-api-version-selected: 2022-11-28
X-RateLimit-Limit: 5000
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 4973
X-RateLimit-Reset: 1676532832
X-RateLimit-Used: 27
X-RateLimit-Resource: core
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: ETag, Link, Location, Retry-After, X-GitHub-OTP, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-RateLimit-Used, X-RateLimit-Resource, X-RateLimit-Reset, X-OAuth-Scopes, X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes, X-Poll-Interval, X-GitHub-Media-Type, X-GitHub-SSO, X-GitHub-Request-Id, Deprecation, Sunset
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 0
Referrer-Policy: origin-when-cross-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'
Vary: Accept-Encoding, Accept, X-Requested-With
X-GitHub-Request-Id: 1826:0605:C27EE8:D02D1B:63EDD47C
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 74
}}  System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage*

I have double checked the repoOwner and repoName variables, so I am unsure why this is returning a 404 error. SO once again, if anyone has any ideas, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Is it a POST or a PUT?

Comment: The code is currently set up to use a PUT, but I am happy to change this to a POST if you think it would make it work properly.

Having said that, I tried changing the following line: `var response = await client.PutAsync(requestUri, content);`  To: `var response = await client.PostAsync(requestUri, content);` And I got the same result.